# How to only allow a specific number to be added to a field in a table when inserting

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

My problem is something with the count and if I try it another way by comparing the emp_id it doesn't allow me to say emp_id > 10 because its of type char. I've tried a lot of things to check if the rows are greater or equal to 10 but so far haven't been able to find anything that works for me. I will place a snipet from my stored procedure.

```
 begin
     if exists (select emp_id from employee where pub_id = @pubId group by emp_id having count(emp_id) > 10)
     throw 500001, 'Only 10 employees can be assigned to a publisher',1
     end
```

Comment: Simple write subquery part as `(select COUNT(DISTINCT on emp_id) from employee where pub_id = @pubId) > 10;`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using a count and check again that? I see you have a count in your condition part, that isn’t what I am talking about.

```
 begin
     if (select count(*) from employee where pub_id = @pubId) > 10
     throw 500001, 'Only 10 employees can be assigned to a publisher',1
     end
```

You may have to store that select statement into a variable and then check against the value that is returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below logic. Remember, This is just an idea that how you can restrict insert row for a single emp_id up to 10 records.

```
INSERT INTO employee(emp_id,Col1,Col2,Col3)
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT @emp_id,@Col1,@Col2,@Col3 
    -- Values are parameter value passed to the stored procedure
) A
WHERE 10 > (
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM employee 
    WHERE pub_id = @pubId 
    AND emp_id = @emp_id 
    -- If I guess correct, You need 10 same emp_id per pub_id
    -- If requirement is different, you can adjust your logic here
    -- like you can remove the filter AND emp_id = @emp_id
    -- This will consider any 10 records for the pub_id
)
```